# Change attribute of selection option based on input field value

Tags: html, jquery

I've been googling and checking around but have not found an answer to this, and am not sure how to go about doing so.

I have a text-input field where a user can type in a value.  While they are typing it in, I wanted the drop-down next to it to change to the option with a value that matches it.

```
<input type="text" name="search" maxlength="6" id="search" />
<select name="custlist" id="custlist">
<option value="" selected>---SELECT ONE--</option>
<option value="100123">Customer 1</option>
<option value="100124">Customer 2</option>
etc., etc.,
</select>
```

So if I start typing 1001... into the text input, it would change the selected option to match the input text.

I already have it working the other way around where if you select an option, it will auto-fill the input text field with the option value (see below).

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="search" maxlength="6" id="search" />
<select name="custlist" id="custlist" onchange="changeFunc()">
<option value="" selected>---SELECT ONE--</option>
<option value="100123">Customer 1</option>
<option value="100124">Customer 2</option>
etc., etc.,
</select>
```

jquery

```
function changeFunc(){
var x = document.getElementById("custlist").value;
document.getElementById("search").value = x;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: UI-wise, why would you need two action elements for the seemingly same purpose? Why not just have the `<select>` box?

Comment: Also, why have you tagged the question [jQuery] if you're using plain JavaScript?

Comment: What means: *"Change attribute of selection option"* ? What select *attribute*?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I think they mean that they want to filter the dropdown to just the matching options.

Comment: The reason for why this was question was asked:

I am trying to make it where if the user enters the customer ID#, it will auto-select the customer name from the drop-down, and vice versa if the user selects a customer from the drop-down, it auto-fills the customer ID# in the text input field.

This is so that if someone knows the customer ID, it will auto-select the customer name to verify that that is indeed the correct ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of Array.prototype.filter() and the Element's `hidden` attribute and the following:

```js
const el = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelector(sel);
const els = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelectorAll(sel);

const elSearch = el("#search");
const elCustlist = el("#custlist");
const elsCustlistOpts = els("option:not([disabled])", elCustlist);

const selectCustlistOption = () => {
  const search = elSearch.value.trim();
  const filteredOpt = [...elsCustlistOpts].filter(elOpt => {
    const match = elOpt.value.includes(search);
    elOpt.hidden = !match;
    return match;
  });
  elCustlist.value = filteredOpt.length ? filteredOpt[0].value : "";
};

elSearch.addEventListener("input", selectCustlistOption);
```

```html
Find by customer ID: <input type="text" name="search" maxlength="6" id="search" />
<select name="custlist" id="custlist">
  <option value="" selected>—SELECT ONE—</option>
  <option value="100123">Customer 1</option>
  <option value="100124">Customer 2</option>
  <option value="100235">Customer 6</option>
  etc., etc.,
</select>
```

Comment: This works perfectly!  Thank you!

Any recommendations for javascript tutorials/snippet examples I can use for future projects?  I am developing using HTML/mysqli/PHP 8/AJAX/javascript.

I'm comfortable with the PHP side, but not so much javascript/AJAX.

Comment: @Bryan I don't want to be overly biased over some tutorials over the others. And if I started the list would get pretty long. Some online frontend "academies" are a nice resource to start with. Also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Front-end_web_developer is a reasonable place to start. Also I'd suggest a framework like the super popular, reasonably simple, blazing fast, actually reactive, the amazing Svelte and SvelteKit.